# A noetherian ring $R$ which is commutative integral domain but not a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for an example of a ring $R$ which is a commutative and Noetherian integral domain but not a PID. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ideal $$I = \langle 2, x\rangle$$ is not principal.

Comment: @MatHeMatCian You're very welcome.

Answer (score 8):

$$\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$$

$$(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}) = 2\cdot3$$

---

$$\mathbf R[x,y]$$

$$(x,y)$$

Comment: @MatHeMatCian My pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Every PID is [1-dimensional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension). There are noetherian integral domains of arbitrary given dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for example $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. There is even an infinite-dimensional noetherian integral domain: Localize $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$ at the complement of $(x_1) \cup (x_2,x_3) \cup (x_4,x_5,x_6) \cup \dotsc$ (this example is due to Nagata).