# Noetherian ring that is not principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples

I know that if a ring is principal, then it is Noetherian. If the converse was true, I would have been told.

I know that a ring is noetherian if and only if any ideal of $A$ is generated by a finite number of elements. Then the counterexamples I am looking for is a ring that satisfies the last statement but has an ideal with at least two generators. Hence, is $\Bbb Z[t]$ a good example ? It is not principal but I don't know if all its ideals are generated by a finite number of elements.

My second idea was something like $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ but I ignore many things about ideals of products. I read somewhere that ideals of $A \times B$ with $A,B$ rings are of the form $I \times J$ with $I$ ideal of $A$ and $J$ ideal of $B$. So the ideals of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ are of the form $(n) \times (m)$ but is that really generated by a finite number of elements of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ ?

Can someone help me find a good counterexample ?

Comment: $k[x,y]$ with $k$ a field

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574141/a-noetherian-ring-r-which-is-commutative-integral-domain-but-not-a-pid